# How to get the result based on custom sorting in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-5

We have a usecase to get the result based on custom sorting from Elasticsearch.

We are using

> Elasticsearch v 5.1.2

EX:
Unique number and respective documents are indexed in elasticsearch

```
arr = [[1,"a b c"],[2, "x y z"], [3, "a x"], ......] # more than 1million
#client_obj is a elasticsearch object
for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
  client_obj.index  :index=> "test", :type=> 'texts' , :body=>{ :number=> arr[0],:text=>arr[1]}
```

arr = [1,3,200,100,2,10 ...] # 1million entry

From array(arr), i am expecting results as the number ordered in array from Elasticsearch. I used below API to get the results. It worked for small set of numbers but if array size is more than 500k then function block in API will increase and my ES server is going down.

```
#from and size value will very based on page number and size
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [ { "terms": { "number" :  [1,3,200,100,2] }} ]
                }
            }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {   "filter": { "term": { "number": 1 } }, "weight" : 4 },
        {   "filter": { "term": { "number": 3 } }, "weight" : 3 },
        {   "filter": { "term": { "number": 200 } }, "weight" : 2 },
        {   "filter": { "term": { "number": 100 } }, "weight" : 1 },
        {   "filter": { "term": { "number": 2 } }, "weight" : 0 }
       ]
    }
  },
  "_source": ["number"],
  "size": 3,
  "from": 0
}
```

**I have following queries**

1. Do we have any other way to solve this problem?
2. Can we use script in ES API to solve this problem? if yes how to do that?

Please help me to solve this problem

Thanks in advance.